# Platform to create one-way video feedback/questionnaire

Tags: video-recording

For a master theses I am looking for a video feedback/questionnaire service. I searched a lot, but I don't find any website or application which fulfills my needs. I should work like this:

- I send my customer/interview partner a mail with a link.
- The customer/interview partner opens the webpage. On this webpage he click the "Start Recording" button
- He records a video with his web-camera
- After video is finished, I can visit the website and watch his video

I don't want to ask the customer to follow the "How to create a YouTube-Chanel" tutorial, and I don't want to send him an invitation for an online Teams/Zoom meeting. And it should be web-based, i.e. the customer does not need to install any software.

A free service would be nice, but I am also willing to pay for it. I plan to quiz only a few persons.

All tools I found are either classic sharing platforms where the customer has to initiate the video recording or where I could provide a video to my customer. That's not what I need.

It would be also OK, to find a tool which I can deploy on my private webspace (would to be based on MySQL, PHP, perl or of course JavaScript on Client side)

Any proposals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one: https://www.vocaroo.com/

It records only audio, no videos. But it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).